# C MySQL Types Error

Tags: mysql, c

I'm trying to store results taken from a MySQL query into an array of structs.  I can't seem to get the types to work though, and I've found the MySQL documentation difficult to sort through.

My struct is:

```
struct login_session
{
    char* user[10];
    time_t time;
    int length;
};
```

And the loop where I'm trying to get the data is:

```
while ( (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL ) {
    strcpy(records[cnt].user, &row[0]);
    cnt++;
}
```

No matter what I try though I constantly get the error:

```
test.c:45: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/string.h:128: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
test.c:45: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/string.h:128: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘MYSQL_ROW’
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple problems, all related to pointers and arrays, I recommend you do some reading.

First, `char * user[10]` is defining an array of 10 `char *` values, not an array of `char`, which is was I suspect you want. The warning even says as much, `strcpy()` expects a `char *`, the user field on its own is seen as a `char **`.

Second, you're one `&` away from what you want in the second argument.

Copied from mysql.h header:

```
typedef char **MYSQL_ROW;       /* return data as array of strings */
```

A `MYSQL_ROW` is an array of `char` arrays. Using `[]` does a dereference, so you dereference down to a `char *` which is what `strcpy()` takes, but then you take the address of it using `&`.

Your code should look more like this:

```
struct login_session
{
    char user[10];
    time_t time;
    int length;
};

while ( (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL ) {
    strcpy(records[cnt].user, row[0]);
    cnt++;
}
```

I don't know what guarantees you have about the data coming from mysql, but if you can't be absolutely sure that the rows are `<= 10` characters long and null (`'\0'`) terminated, you should use `strncpy()` to avoid any possibility of overflowing the `user` array.

Comment: He can get the lengths of the columns of the current row within a result by calling mysql_fetch_lengths(), then allocate the memory and copy the content.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll take your advice and do some additional reading on pointers.